# poi shiftRows resizes and does not move images

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm using POI and i want to insert some lines in a xlsx. In this file, I have some images inside a table. When i shift rows by doing this :

```
sheet.shiftRows(30, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 10, true, true);
```

some images are in the wrong place and are resized.

How can I move all the items at once without resizing images and let them in the right place?

Comment: shiftRows probably doesn't do much with images, as this is a less common/more advanced use case. Ask this question over on the POI mailing list if you want another set of ears.

Comment: yes... I finally used a copy method with styles etc. and then, I copy images "manually"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this issue and this code worked for me
Basically what needs to happen is change the anchors for the images to reflect the new row indexes.

```
XSSFDrawing drawings = mainSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
for(XSSFShape shape : drawings.getShapes()){
    if(shape instanceof Picture){
        XSSFPicture picture = (XSSFPicture) shape;
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = picture.getClientAnchor();
        int row1 = anchor.getRow1();
        if (row1 >= 30 && row1 <= mainSheet.getLastRowNum()) {
            int row2 = anchor.getRow2();
            anchor.setRow1(row1 + 10);
            anchor.setRow2(row2 + 10);
        }
     }
 }
```

This is what happens :

- Get all the drawings in the current sheet.
- Check if the image row1 anchor is within the range of rows being shifted
- Set the new row1 anchor to be the old row1 anchor + the number of rows being shifted
- Set the new row2 anchor to be the old row1 anchor + the number of rows being shifted

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't comment. But in my setup, the first line of John Muiruris answer should be:

`XSSFDrawing drawings = (XSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();`

Just to avoid any confusion.